# Как расшифровать бинарные данные на Delphi?

Tags: java, delphi

Есть рабочее приложение, написанное на Java. Она отправляет запрос на сервер и получает запакованные данные.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2023 18:26:21 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Encoding: zip-block
Content-Length: 24640

D @xњіIО+¶іHML±іQЊvvq qЊV°
ВИКМMµURRHN¶U26VиГИС
¶S‚ЌµиС‡(OОЛ¶и V» & D @x.
```

Полный ответ - [Response.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_S45rVs9S_1Fkf8i12kCz7sw_3LgwbAK/view?usp=share_link)

При обработке ответа в TidCompressorZlib (Delphi, компонент ZLIB для работы с gzip) получаю ошибку о неправильном формате архивных данных.

Я так понимаю, что при отправке данных происходит еще дополнительно некое их "шифрование".

Я вытащил два блока кода программы на Java:

1. Модуль CompressedBlockInputStream

   ```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;
    import java.util.zip.Inflater;

    public class CompressedBlockInputStream extends FilterInputStream
    {

    public CompressedBlockInputStream(InputStream inputstream)
        throws IOException
    {
        super(inputstream);
        inBuf = null;
        inLength = 0;
        outBuf = null;
        outOffs = 0;
        outLength = 0;
        inflater = null;
        inflater = new Inflater();
    }

    protected void readAndDecompress()
        throws IOException
    {
        int i = in.read();
        int j = in.read();
        int k = in.read();
        int l = in.read();
        if((i | j | k | l) < 0)
            throw new EOFException();
        inLength = (i << 24) + (j << 16) + (k << 8) + (l << 0);
        i = in.read();
        j = in.read();
        k = in.read();
        l = in.read();
        if((i | j | k | l) < 0)
            throw new EOFException();
        outLength = (i << 24) + (j << 16) + (k << 8) + (l << 0);
        if(inBuf == null || inLength > inBuf.length)
            inBuf = new byte[inLength];
        if(outBuf == null || outLength > outBuf.length)
            outBuf = new byte[outLength];
        int j1;
        for(int i1 = 0; i1 < inLength; i1 += j1)
        {
            j1 = in.read(inBuf, i1, inLength - i1);
            if(j1 == -1)
                throw new EOFException();
        }

        inflater.setInput(inBuf, 0, inLength);
        try
        {
            inflater.inflate(outBuf);
        }
        catch(DataFormatException dataformatexception)
        {
            throw new IOException((new StringBuilder()).append("Data format exception - ").append(dataformatexception.getMessage()).toString());
        }
        inflater.reset();
        outOffs = 0;
    }

    public int read()
        throws IOException
    {
        if(outOffs >= outLength)
            try
            {
                readAndDecompress();
            }
            catch(EOFException eofexception)
            {
                return -1;
            }
        return outBuf[outOffs++] & 0xff;
    }

    public int read(byte abyte0[], int i, int j)
        throws IOException
    {
        int k = 0;
    _L3:
        if(k >= j) goto _L2; else goto _L1
    _L1:
        if(outOffs < outLength)
            break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_58;
        try
        {
            if(k > 0 && in.available() == 0)
                return k;
        }
        catch(EOFException eofexception)
        {
            if(k == 0)
                k = -1;
            return k;
        }
        readAndDecompress();
        int l = Math.min(outLength - outOffs, j - k);
        System.arraycopy(outBuf, outOffs, abyte0, i + k, l);
        outOffs += l;
        k += l;
          goto _L3
    _L2:
        return k;
    }

    public int available()
        throws IOException
    {
        return (outLength - outOffs) + in.available();
    }

    protected byte inBuf[];
    protected int inLength;
    protected byte outBuf[];
    protected int outOffs;
    protected int outLength;
    protected Inflater inflater;
    }
   ```
2. Модуль CompressedBlockOutputStream

   ```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.zip.Deflater;

    public class CompressedBlockOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream
    {

    public CompressedBlockOutputStream(OutputStream outputstream, int i)
        throws IOException
    {
        this(outputstream, i, -1, 0);
    }

    public CompressedBlockOutputStream(OutputStream outputstream, int i, int j, int k)
        throws IOException
    {
        super(outputstream);
        inBuf = null;
        outBuf = null;
        len = 0;
        deflater = null;
        inBuf = new byte[i];
        outBuf = new byte[i + 64];
        deflater = new Deflater(j);
        deflater.setStrategy(k);
    }

    protected void compressAndSend()
        throws IOException
    {
        if(len > 0)
        {
            deflater.setInput(inBuf, 0, len);
            deflater.finish();
            int i = deflater.deflate(outBuf);
            out.write(i >> 24 & 0xff);
            out.write(i >> 16 & 0xff);
            out.write(i >> 8 & 0xff);
            out.write(i >> 0 & 0xff);
            out.write(len >> 24 & 0xff);
            out.write(len >> 16 & 0xff);
            out.write(len >> 8 & 0xff);
            out.write(len >> 0 & 0xff);
            out.write(outBuf, 0, i);
            out.flush();
            len = 0;
            deflater.reset();
        }
    }

    public void write(int i)
        throws IOException
    {
        inBuf[len++] = (byte)i;
        if(len == inBuf.length)
            compressAndSend();
    }

    public void write(byte abyte0[], int i, int j)
        throws IOException
    {
        int k;
        for(; len + j > inBuf.length; j -= k)
        {
            k = inBuf.length - len;
            System.arraycopy(abyte0, i, inBuf, len, k);
            len += k;
            compressAndSend();
            i += k;
        }

        System.arraycopy(abyte0, i, inBuf, len, j);
        len += j;
    }

    public void flush()
        throws IOException
    {
        compressAndSend();
        out.flush();
    }

    public void close()
        throws IOException
    {
        compressAndSend();
        out.close();
    }

    protected byte inBuf[];
    protected byte outBuf[];
    protected int len;
    protected Deflater deflater;
    }
   ```

Прошу помощи в переносе кода с Java на Delphi или
в понимании этой логики "упаковки" и "шифрования" данных

Comment: Ваши внешние ссылки на Драйв протухнут через неделю и вопрос станет полностью бесполезным для ruSO. Пожалуйста вычлените и включите все релевантное в сам вопрос.

Comment: какие-то странные телодвижения с записью/чтением побайтово двух интов в начало. считайте их отдельном мб

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже написали в комментариях - там два лишних int в данных. Вот так работает, по крайней мере у меня на полном файле:

```
var zipBlock := TFile.ReadAllBytes('T:\RadStudio\Response.txt');
ZDecompress(@zipBlock[8], Length(zipBlock) - 8, Data, Size);
```

Comment: Спасибо !!!. Декомпрессия работает без ошибки. Но есть один нюанс. Отправляю разные запросы, получаю разные по размеру "Response.txt", но после декомпрессии получаю одинаковую строку;
<cns><head><![CDATA[ <RS name="" cc="33">
</RS> ]]></head><cnk><

Comment: Это уже вопрос к разработчику сервера - что она означает.

Comment: По факту распаковывается только начало данных. Возможно первые 8 байт. Как вытянуть остальную информацию?

Comment: В примере файл Response.txt - 50,41 Кб, а распакованных данных 64 байт. Т.е. распаковывается в примере только начало Response.txt.

Comment: Возможно там несколько последовательных сжатых блоков. Что означает "cc = 33"?..

Answer (score 0):

Тему закрываю. Вопрос решен.
Благодарю [Alekcvp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/206219/alekcvp), [Shaft](https://delphisources.ru/forum/member.php?u=24791) за помощь.

Код от [Shaft](https://delphisources.ru/forum/member.php?u=24791)

```
procedure decompress;
var
  s_dec:TDecompressionStream;
  s_in,s_out:TMemoryStream;
const block=64;
      offset=8;
begin
  s_in:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  s_out:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  s_in.LoadFromFile('test.bin');
  repeat
    s_in.Position:=s_in.Position+offset;
    s_dec:=TDecompressionStream.Create(s_in);
    if s_in.Position+block<=s_in.Size then
      s_out.CopyFrom(s_dec,block)
    else
      s_out.CopyFrom(s_dec,s_in.Size-s_in.Position-offset);
    s_dec.Free;
  until s_in.Position>=s_in.Size;
  s_out.SaveToFile('decompress.bin');
  s_in.Free;
  s_out.Free;
end;
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).